# How can I fix this Excel Workbook Linking Error

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to change links between workbooks and usually they're fine but I'm receiving an error now that says, " you can't enter this formula because it has too many values cell references and/or names." I understand what it says but I'm not too sure how to rectify it. Can anyone help?

Comment: Welcome to SO. I think it might help if you edit your question and you add your formula. Also, if you could explain whata re you trying to achieve, maybe somebody here in SO will be able to make an answer or advice that might help you.

Comment: Unfortunately the file is very large and the error is not pointing to a singular formula. I'm just wondering if anyone has an idea of potential causes.

Comment: sample data/case should be fine.. we don't need the whole data.. just recreate the case on a new file/files.. such a sample should be fine.. (:

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and found a workaround:
Instead of using the Edit Links function, use the Find and Replace function and replace the old file reference with the new file reference.